# use LINQ to find which element "scores highest" on a certain function

Tags: c#, linq

If I have an

```
IEnumerable<Something>
```

and a function that takes a Something, and return an int, how would I use LINQ to tell me which of my somethings gives the highest result when fed to my function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like [`MaxBy` from `MoreLinq`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) (or simply use [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)):

```
public static TSource MaxBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> selector, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
{
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> sourceIterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!sourceIterator.MoveNext())
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence was empty");
        TSource max = sourceIterator.Current;
        TKey maxKey = selector(max);

        while (sourceIterator.MoveNext())
        {
            TSource candidate = sourceIterator.Current;
            TKey candidateProjected = selector(candidate);
            if (comparer.Compare(candidateProjected, maxKey) > 0)
            {
                max = candidate;
                maxKey = candidateProjected;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855.aspx):

```
Something result = yourEnumerable.OrderByDescending(x => f(x)).First();
```

Note that this results in a O(n log n) sort if you are using LINQ to Objects.

You could also use `MaxBy` from [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/):

```
Something result = yourEnumerable.MaxBy(x => f(x));
```

Comment: I did a quick test using LINQ to Objects, which showed that f(x) is called only once for each element in the list (despite the sort).

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge: Yes, I think you are right. I believe that `OrderBy` first calls the projection function on each element and stores the result in a list, then sorts that. So it's not only ineffecient in speed, but it also consumes far more memory than a simple linear search like that performed by MaxBy in MoreLINQ.

Answer (score 1):

```
var something= List.Aggregate((p, q) => func(p) > func(q) ? p : q)
```

This aggregate is simple but call func method occured twice for max in per iteration, to avoid this:

```
var something=List.Select(p => new { something = p, call = func(p) })
                        .Aggregate((p, q) => p.call > q.call ? p : q).something;
```

Comment: This gives the maximum `func(p)`. The question was how to find the `p` for which `func(p)` gives the maximum result.

Comment: The result of `List.Max(p=>func(p))` will be one of the values obtained by calling `func`. It won't be the `Something` that was used in the call, which is what the question asks for.

Answer (score -1):

somethings.Max(p => p.intFunc());